# How can i get the DTU percentage of an Azure database using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

How can i get the DTU Percentage of a database using powershell ?

Currently i am running the query

```
    SELECT    
AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Average CPU Utilization In Percent',   
MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Maximum CPU Utilization In Percent',   
AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Average Data IO In Percent',   
MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Maximum Data IO In Percent',   
AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Average Log Write Utilization In Percent',   
MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Maximum Log Write Utilization In Percent',   
AVG(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Average Memory Usage In Percent',   
MAX(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Maximum Memory Usage In Percent'   
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats;
```

But this requires connecting to the database every time. Is there a powershell command i can run that will give me the DTU percentage for a certain time period ?

Comment: A quick google came up with this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/how-to-query-azure-sql-metrics-using-powershell/ba-p/1753305. You'll still need to authenticate to the control plane

Comment: I assume the timegrain is 5 and the metricname is dtu_consumption_percent ?  what is daystolook ?

Comment: I'm not sure what daystolook is. It isn't in this sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scripts/monitor-and-scale-database-powershell?view=azuresql#sample-script

Comment: Have tried it but get the error :    Get-AzMetric : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 
'BadRequest'

Comment: or how can iu get the maximum as this gives average

Comment: I've never used this before I'm just going from the same doco that's available to you. In the sample code there is line `-TimeAggregation Average` I assume you change that to `Maximum`. You'll need to experiment to get it working. I suggest you start with the simplest syntax and see if it works and go from there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetric?view=azps-10.0.0#example-1-get-a-metric-with-summarized-output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the metric name is not given correctly, the ***"Bad request"*** error appears with the `Get-AzMetric` command.

To get the DTU percentage of an Azure database using PowerShell, you need to provide the metric name as `dtu_consumption_percent`.

**Note:** Supported database metrics are listed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftsqlserversdatabases) for your reference.

```
$Metrics = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<servername>/databases/<Databasename>" -MetricName "dtu_consumption_percent" -TimeGrain 00:05:00 -AggregationType Maximum -DetailedOutput
$Metrics.data
```

[image]

*Alternatively, you can also write a script with the required parameters as shown below.*

```
$MonitorParameters = @{                  
ResourceId ="/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<servername>/databases/<Databasename>"
MetricNames = "dtu_consumption_percent"
}
$Metrics = Get-AzMetric @MonitorParameters -DetailedOutput
```

[image]

*If you want to retrieve the data metrics clearly, use* `$Metrics.data` *in the above script*.